# MySQL match against syntax error

Tags: php, mysql, debugging, search, syntax-error

I'm using a search script from here: http://www.maiansearch.com/

The script runs fine on localhost but shows up the following error on live host.

```
> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'MATCH (title,description,keywords) AGAINST('somesearchterm' at line 1
```

Mysql version on live host is 5.1

Here's the part of script where it's pointing the error

```
$sCount=rowCount('search_pages','WHERE MATCH(title,description,keywords) AGAINST(\''.safeImport($searchterm).'\' IN BOOLEAN MODE)');
$s_query=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM ".$database['prefix']."search_pages WHERE MATCH(title,description,keywords) AGAINST ('".safeImport($searchterm)."' IN BOOLEAN MODE) ORDER BY title LIMIT $limit,$SETTINGS->total") or die(mysql_error());
```

What is the problem?

Comment: What is the MySQL version of the localhost if the live version is 5.1?

Comment: Possibly related? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21556823/mysql-5-0-upgrade-to-5-1-match-function

Comment: Another related question/issue though it looks like your code already has what the answer to this question suggests: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14775119/mysql-match-against-not-working

Comment: yes, I've already implemented BOOLEAN MODE but still unable to figure where the problem is?

Comment: can you output the actual query, like this `echo "SELECT * FROM ".$database['prefix']."search_pages WHERE MATCH(title,description,keywords) AGAINST ('".safeImport($searchterm)."' IN BOOLEAN MODE) ORDER BY title LIMIT $limit,$SETTINGS->total") `, as we don't know what safeImport will return